# Generate a square thumbnail image regardless the image ratio

Tags: html, css, image

I am looking for a CSS only solution to generate a square thumbnail regardless an image ratio:

```
.thumbnail {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The example above will create a square thumbnail only if the image is a portrait view, landscape view images won't cover the full height of the thumbnail.

**Is there a CSS only solution (*besides setting it as a background image*) to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way (I think) of doing this without the usual `background-image / background-size` method is to use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit). Though it won't work in IE:

```css
.thumbnail {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

/* for demo only...*/
div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
.noscale {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/200/300">
</div>

<div class="thumbnail">
  <img src="//placekitten.com/300/200">
</div>

<h4>
Images for reference:
</h4>
<img src="//placekitten.com/200/300" class="noscale">
<img src="//placekitten.com/300/200" class="noscale">
```

[Browser Support #object-fit](http://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

Comment: WOW, never heard of this one before. Thank you very much!